# Why don't I get json data in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I have a class in a webapi

```
public class Respuesta
{
    public int Exito { get; set; }
    public string Mensaje { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

and have the following method in ASP.NetCore:

```
public IActionResult Get()
{ ..
using (NegociosAPIContext db = new NegociosAPIContext())
                {
                    var lst = db.Cliente.ToList();
                    oRespuesta.Exito = 1;
                    oRespuesta.Data = lst;
                    return Ok(oRespuesta);
                }
```

In the otherside (appAngular), I did the import in module.ts 
`import {HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';` 
and it´s my code service:

**Image**

[image]

and on my controller

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ApiclienteService} from '../service/apicliente.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cliente',
...
})
export class ClienteComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private apiCliente: ApiclienteService) {
    apiCliente.getClientes().subscribe(response => {
      console.log('respuesta:'+response);

    })
   }
…
}
```

If I make a call to the api in the browser, I get this

```
{
    "exito":1, 
    "mensaje":" ",
    "data":[
        {
            "id":1, 
            "nombre":"Liliana  Torres"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "nombre":"Redmon Redinton"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then in Angular app, I get only the {object Object}. When I try to put       `console.log('respuesta:'+response.json);` this throws
 `undefined`

An important that i forget was mi class in typescript; i have:

```
import { Icliente } from './ICliente';

export interface Response {
    exito:number;
    mensaje:string;
    data:Icliente[];
}
```

Comment: instead of `console.log('respuesta:'+response);` can you 
try: ` console.log('respuesta:', response);`

Comment: You should have get `data:{"exito":1,"mensaje":null,"data":[{"id":1,"nombre":"Redmon Redinton"}]}`. I think `:` is missing after the first data and a `}` is missing at the end.

Comment: @Sébastien Temprado i update my string to :     {"exito":1,"mensaje":" ","data":[{"id":1,"nombre":"Liliana  Torres"},{"id":2,"nombre":"Redmon Redinton"}]} and i test in JSON Validator its ok, but i can´t obtaint mi [data]

Answer (score 1):

Here is your json which is in `response` :

```
{
    "exito":1, 
    "mensaje":" ",
    "data":[
        {
            "id":1, 
            "nombre":"Liliana  Torres"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "nombre":"Redmon Redinton"
        }
    ]
}
```

To access to an attribute in this json, you can do (for example, for `mensaje`):

`response.mensaje`

To get `Liliana  Torres` : `response.data[0].nombre`.

`response.data[0]` is equal to :

```
{
    "id":1, 
    "nombre":"Liliana  Torres"
}
```

and so on.

If you want to log the full json, use:

`console.log('respuesta:', response);`

or

`console.log('respuesta:' + JSON.stringify(response));`

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting is an object. So in order to get the data of the object, you can do it like this.

```
    console.log('respuesta:' response['data']);
```

Let me know if this solves your issue. Thank you.

Comment: thanks @Parween Kelappan, but i put: ´console.log('respuesta:'+respons['exito']);
      console.log('resp develop:'+respons['data']);´ however its throw:   respuesta:1
resp develop:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]